# How can I remove the last three pages of a set of PDF files using pdf-stapler?

Tags: pdf

I have a large set of PDF files, each of which contains three unnecessary pages at the end. I was originally trying to create a solution based on an answer I found on [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/960512/791808) and [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705974/remove-the-last-page-of-a-pdf-file-using-pdftk), but pdf-stapler apparently doesn't support the "r" notation that pdftk did, e.g. if I try `pdf-stapler del myFile.pdf r4-r1 outputFiles/myFile.pdf` or `pdf-stapler cat myFile.pdf 1-r4 outputFiles/myFile.pdf`, I get an error saying "Invalid range: r4-r1" for the first option and an output file with only page 1 for the second option.

Is there a way to do this with pdf-stapler?

Comment: Are you limited to pdf-stapler? Or can a solution use another command line tool?

Comment: @gettalong I'd prefer to stick to tools available through the Fedora repository, which eliminates pdftk, unfortunately. Aside from that, I could use another tool.

Answer (score 2):

The `qpdf` CLI command should be available in the Fedora repositories. It supports the "r" notation, so removing the last three pages from a file should work like this:

```
qpdf --pages myFile.pdf 1-r4 -- myFile.pdf outputFiles/myFile.pdf
```